# Laravel 5 PDO error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, laravel-5

I recently copied a completed Laravel 5 project from a colleague who is using a Mac system to my Mac, we have the same configuration, I have been having error: "at

`PDO->__construct('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tezzadev', 'root', '', array('0', '2', '0', false, '0')) in Connector.php line 50".`

Even when we have same database parameters.
I'm dumbfounded, any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Does the db exist, can you connect to it through other tools?

Comment: Yes, I connected using terminal and mysql workbench

Comment: Have you tried connecting using the IP address instead?

Comment: Also just wondering if you had the pdo_mysql module on your machine - you can run phpinfo() to see if it is there.

Comment: @Mhluzi Bhaka, that was it. Connecting through IP. I wonder why that should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried connecting using the IP address instead?

(Adding this as an answer so that you can select that if you wish!)

I seem to remember having a similar issue on this a while back - will try and recall what I did to sort it out.